# Access log not created

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to enable SpringBoot's embedded Tomcat access logs.  When the application starts I'm not seeing the log file at all.  When I make requests to the application from browser I still get nothing.  What am I missing?

This should be really straight forward.  I'm wondering if there's stuff in my project that's interfering with Tomcat logging to the access_log.log file.  Within the project I've done the following:

- enable ssl and changed port
- Via `@Configuration`, I created a `@Bean EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` that adds a `TomcatConnectorCustomizer`.
- Added Spring Security to request authentication for /secure/** URL patterns.

From what I've read none of that should require anything special regarding Tomcat access logs.  With my set up I expect the logging to be in *my-tomcat/access_log.log* at the same location I ran the java -jar command.  Correct me if that's wrong.

Using...

- SpringBoot 1.5.9.RELEASE
- Win 7 Enterprise

### application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    # 6.2 Ensure SSLEnabled is set to True for Sensitive Connectors (Not Scored)
    enabled: true

    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: tomcat

    # 6.5 Ensure SSL Protocol is set to TLS for Secure Connectors (Scored)
    protocol: TLS

    tomcat:
      basedir: my-tomcat
      accesslog:
        enabled: true
        pattern: '%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)'

security:
  require-ssl: true

# 7.1 Application specific logging (Scored)
logging:
  level.com.esd.springbootdemo: DEBUG
  # 7.2 Specify file handler in logging.properties files (Scored)
  file: logs/springbootdemo.log
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.esd.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springboot-demo</name>
    <description>Spring Boot security and hardening POC</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tomcat` YAML block is currently a child of the `ssl` YAML block - so you need to fix the indentation